# Add rel=canonical to only one page

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm trying to add the `rel="canonical"` tag to only one page, the home page. In order to add the tag, I need to add it to the `<head>` part of the template, in the header.php file. This will add the same rel canonical tag to all the pages of my wordpress website.

How can I add rel canonical to only one page, the home page. I don't want to do a 301 redirect, I want to add a rel canonical tag.

Or can this be done with some htaccess code (but no 301 redirect)?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are on the front page with `is_front_page()`. The *home* page (in WordPress the page with the latest posts) can be checked with `is_home()`.

You can add this to the `header.php` between `<head>` and `</head>`:

```
<?php
if ( is_front_page() )
    echo '<link rel="canonical" href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" />';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'm quite a noob at this and so is my next questions: do i have to add this in the <head> part or in the home page template? i'm 90% sure this must be in the head, but still, i need to be 100% sure...

Comment: @user3288194 See my update.

Comment: Thanks for the update, i'm still being a noob, don't know where to add the url in there... until now i used: <link rel=”canonical” href=”http://xxx.website.com” /> where do i put that xxx.website.com in your code?

Comment: @user3288194 The URL is built automatically by `home_url( '/' )`. Please test my code, and you will see it.

Comment: yea i understand the url is built automatically but where to insert the url i want to direct to? maybe i didn't explain this correctly. i have 2 urls: website.com (which is the wordpress homepage) and xxx.website.com (which is a standalone page on a subdomain). i want to point website.com to xxx.website.com via rel canonical...

Comment: @user3288194 `rel=canonical` is not a redirect, just a hint for search engines.

Comment: exactly that's what i want, a hint for search engines...

Comment: i'm pretty sure that an IF STATEMENT would work perfectly here, i just don't know how to put everything together. would this work? <?php
if ( is_front_page() )
    echo '<link rel="canonical" href="http://xxx.website.com" />';
?>

Comment: @user3288194 That’s **exactly** what my code does. Please **test** it.

Comment: how does your code know what page to target?

Comment: @user3288194 Again `home_url( '/' )` does that. You can also replace that with a fixed value like `http://example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to handle it is to install [Wordpress SEO plugin by Yoast](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) - it will give you many great options, and it will give you your requested option for setting only a certain page with rel="canonical", from within the admin, from the "edit page" page.

This will save you the effort of dealing with the pure php code :)

Comment: Thanks man, i had yoast seo installed but never looked through the advanced options on the edit page seo settings. This is what i needed.

Comment: @user3288194 I presume from your comment that this answer worked. If it did, take the time to mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark just beneath the up/down arrows. This will make the answer useful not just you, but everyone